# Finding Method for Binary Tree doesn't return anything

Tags: python, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a Binary Tree and want to search for elements in it.
But for some reason i'm not getting any output and no error. Tried debugging as well but the code is always being executed until the end.

```
def find(self, i):
   if self.__head is None:
       return -1
   else:
       return self.__find(self.__head, i)

def __find(self, element, i):
    if element is not None:
        if i == element.value():
            return 1
        elif i < element.value():
            self.__find(element.getLeft(), i)
        else:
            self.__find(element.getRight(), i)
    else:
        return -1
```

The code for the Elements is the following:

```
class BElement:
def __init__(self, i, v):
    self.__id = i
    self.__value = v
    self.__left = None
    self.__right = None

def id(self):
    return self.__id

def value(self):
    return self.__value

def getLeft(self):
    return self.__left

def setLeft(self, l):
    self.__left = l

def getRight(self):
    return self.__right

def setRight(self, r):
    self.__right = r

def __str__(self):
    s = "{"
    if self.__left is not None:
        s = s + str(self.__left)
    s = s + str(self.__id) + ":" + str(self.__value)
    if self.__right is not None:
        s = s + str(self.__right)
    s = s + "}"
    return s
```

Comment: it's hard to tell what wrong in the code without seeing getLeft and getRight methods

Comment: @Roim yes sry added it

Comment: The recursive calls to `__find()` are useless, since you throw away their return values.

Comment: @Deaddave19 Why everytime you call again with left or right? Binary Search should "chop" each iteration some of the elements. It seems you always call to the most left or right element

Comment: I would'nt have thought of that. Much thanks Sir.

Comment: @Roim i took the rekursion out and now it works

Answer (score 0):

remove the brackets() after value,left and right they are not methods.